# How to group values posted from HTML form by key if input fields can be dynamically added or deleted

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have a form where rows can be added on click of a button. They can also be removed on click.

My html on page load looks like this:

```
<div class="invoicerow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <label for="">Aantal</label>
      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
        <input type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_quantity]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
      <label for="">Titel</label>
      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
        <input type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_title]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <label for="">Prijs</label>
      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
        <input type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_price]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      <label for="">Totaal</label>
      <div>€99,05</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-1 d-flex align-center">
      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete_invoice_row"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <label for="">Beschrijving</label>
      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
        <textarea type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_desc]"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to group all results together when there are multiple `invoicerow` elements present.

Now when I post the posted array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [other_info] => 
    [invoice_row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_quantity] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_title] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_price] => 
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_desc] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_quantity] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_title] => 
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_price] => 
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_desc] => 
                )

        )

)
```

While this is what I am looking for:

```
Array
(
    [other_info] => 
    [invoice_row] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_quantity] => 
                    [invoice_title] => 
                    [invoice_price] => 
                    [invoice_desc] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [invoice_quantity] => 
                    [invoice_title] => 
                    [invoice_price] => 
                    [invoice_desc] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I know I can change this `invoice_row[][invoice_price]` to `invoice_row[0][invoice_price]` for example to group them but this won't work since my input fields can be dynamically added and removed.

What is the best solution for this?

This is my code that adds and removes the input fields:

```
$(".add_invoice_row").click(function () {
  var invoicehtml = '' + 
  '<div class="invoicerow">' +
  '  <div class="row">' +
  '    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">' +
  '      <label for="">Aantal</label>' +
  '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
  '        <input type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_quantity]">' +
  '      </div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">' +
  '      <label for="">Titel</label>' +
  '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
  '        <input type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_title]">' +
  '      </div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">' +
  '      <label for="">Prijs</label>' +
  '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
  '        <input type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_price]">' +
  '      </div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">' +
  '      <label for="">Totaal</label>' +
  '      <div>€99,05</div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '    <div class="col-12 col-md-1 d-flex align-center">' +
  '      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete_invoice_row"></i>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '    <div class="col-12">' +
  '      <label for="">Beschrijving</label>' +
  '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
  '        <textarea type="text" name="invoice_row[][invoice_desc]"></textarea>' +
  '      </div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '  </div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '';
  $('.new_invoice_row').append(invoicehtml);

  create_invoice_form = $(".create_invoice_form").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:"invoice_custom.php",
    data:({
      create_invoice_form: create_invoice_form
    }),
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.delete_invoice_row', function () {
  $(this).closest('.invoicerow').remove();
});
```

jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/xbLyp9f2/1/

Comment: Added a JSFiddle demonstrating my answer. As you can see it is much easier to maintain the HTML for the template as HTML and not JS strings: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j41fzubp/2/

Answer (score 2):

IMHO: Don't embed HTML literal into your JS code unless really needed. Hide the HTML template in a script tag containing replacement text markers (e.g. for the index).

You can then have an actual index value inserted for each added row (I usually add 1 to the highest existing row value present):

```
<script id="rowtemplate">
    <div class="invoicerow">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <label for="">Aantal</label>
          <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
            <input type="text" name="invoice_row[{row}][invoice_quantity]">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
          <label for="">Titel</label>
          <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
            <input type="text" name="invoice_row[{row}][invoice_title]">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <label for="">Prijs</label>
          <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
            <input type="text" name="invoice_row[{row}][invoice_price]">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <label for="">Totaal</label>
          <div>{total}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-1 d-flex align-center">
          <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete_invoice_row"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <label for="">Beschrijving</label>
          <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
            <textarea type="text" name="invoice_row[{row}][invoice_desc]"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

`$('#rowtemplate').html()` will give you the template as a string.

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j41fzubp/2/

*I left a comment in the JSFiddle where the string replacements would go, but as you have already accepted another answer, I leave it up to you to complete.*

Comment: Thank you. I made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/xbLyp9f2/1/

Comment: Btw I tried your solution of adding the html in a variable but when I click the add button nothing is added.

Comment: @gonecoding I think what you are suggesting is to use html [<template> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

Comment: @onkarruikar. No. What I suggested just works: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j41fzubp/2/

Comment: Yes it does. But the <template> is a new thing. But should you use template is [debatable](https://love2dev.com/blog/should-you-use-the-template-element/).

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=template That came long after I originally solved this. Looks like a more suitable option to the script trick, once all browsers support it fully.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON), a small jquery plugin, to get output in nice JSON format. The JSON can be easily parsed at server side.

```js
$(".add_invoice_row").click(function() {
  var invoicehtml = '' +
    '<div class="invoicerow">' +
    '  <div class="row">' +
    '    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">' +
    '      <label for="">Aantal</label>' +
    '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
    '        <input type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_quantity]">' +
    '      </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '    <div class="col-12 col-md-5">' +
    '      <label for="">Titel</label>' +
    '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
    '        <input type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_title]">' +
    '      </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">' +
    '      <label for="">Prijs</label>' +
    '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
    '        <input type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_price]">' +
    '      </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">' +
    '      <label for="">Totaal</label>' +
    '      <div>€99,05</div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '    <div class="col-12 col-md-1 d-flex align-center">' +
    '      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete_invoice_row"></i>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '    <div class="col-12">' +
    '      <label for="">Beschrijving</label>' +
    '      <div class="inputstyle mb-10">' +
    '        <textarea type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_desc]"></textarea>' +
    '      </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '  </div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '';
  $('.new_invoice_row').append(invoicehtml);
});


//create_invoice_form = $(".create_invoice_form").serialize();
/*$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: "invoice_custom.php",
  data: ({
    create_invoice_form: create_invoice_form
  }),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
*/
function onSubmit(form) {
  var data = $(form).serializeJSON();

  console.log(data);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 3));
  return false;
}

$(document).on('click', '.delete_invoice_row', function() {
  $(this).closest('.invoicerow').remove();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/3.2.1/jquery.serializejson.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-12">
  <p>See the console logs for output.</p>
  <form class="create_invoice_form" method="post" onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button><br><hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="">Emailadres</label>
        <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
          <input type="text" name="invoice[mail]" value='abc@gmail.com'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <label for="">Datum</label>
        <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
          <input type="date" name="invoice[date]">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="invoicerow">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
              <label for="">Aantal</label>
              <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
                <input type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_quantity]" value='10'>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
              <label for="">Titel</label>
              <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
                <input type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_title]" value='item 1'>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
              <label for="">Prijs ex. BTW</label>
              <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
                <input type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_price]" value='btw'>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
              <label for="">Totaal</label>
              <div>€99,05</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-1 d-flex align-center">
              <i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete_invoice_row"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <label for="">Beschrijving</label>
              <div class="inputstyle mb-10">
                <textarea type="text" name="invoice[row][][invoice_desc]">description</textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="new_invoice_row">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col-12">
  <i class="fas fa-plus-square add_invoice_row"></i>
</div>
```

Note how I named the inputs `invoice[row][][invoice_quantity]`.

Output:

```js
{
   "invoice": {
      "mail": "abc@gmail.com",
      "date": "",
      "row": [
         {
            "invoice_quantity": "10",
            "invoice_title": "item 1",
            "invoice_price": "btw",
            "invoice_desc": "description"
         },
         {
            "invoice_quantity": "a",
            "invoice_title": "t",
            "invoice_price": "g",
            "invoice_desc": "sd"
         },
         {
            "invoice_quantity": "3",
            "invoice_title": "3",
            "invoice_price": "3",
            "invoice_desc": "des3"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

In php you can convert the request JSON string to object using `$jObj = json_decode($jsonString);`

Comment: Thanks! Great plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For the dynamic solution (adding the indexes to the form names explicitly) to work reliably, all you need to do is handle the re-indexing when you remove an item:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete_invoice_row', function () {
  $(this).closest('.invoicerow').remove();
  $('.invoicerow').each(function(idx, el) {
    $(el).find('[name^="invoice_row"]').each(function(iidx, iel) {
      $(iel).attr("name", iel.name.replace(/invoice_row\[\d+\]/, "invoice_row[" + idx + "]"));
    });
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fg8rwexp/2/